# I need day to update 1 once my counter hits 00:59 (basiclly 00:00)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can not get the day to increment by 1 im assuming my maths are off.

I will post what i have and what / where the issue is.

1. Counter Works (100%)
2. Put the number into a "id" tag here is what i have below.
3. **I just can not figure out the maths needed to 24 hours for some reason**

```js
let daysLabel = document.getElementById("days");
let minutesLabel = document.getElementById("minutes");
let hoursLabel = document.getElementById("hours");
let totalSeconds = 0;
let dayUpdate = 0;
setInterval(setTime, 10);

function setTime() {
  ++totalSeconds;
  if (totalSeconds / 60 == 24) {
    ++dayUpdate;
    totalSeconds = 0;
  }
  minutesLabel.innerHTML = pad(parseInt(totalSeconds % 60));
  hoursLabel.innerHTML = pad(parseInt(totalSeconds / 60));
  // I belive my maths is wrong why it doesnt update the time.
  daysLabel.innerHTML = pad(parseInt(totalSeconds / 60 == 24));
}

function pad(val) {
  let valString = val + "";
  if (valString.length < 2) {
    return "0" + valString
  }
  return valString
}
```

```html
<label id="days">Day: 1</label> <label id="hours">00</label>:<label id="minutes">00</label><br />
```

Tried to copy the counte info to replicate the days increase but failed.
Can not get the day to Inctrement by +1 every new day based on the timer.

Day 1: 22:59 time changes to 00:00 again and day should increase by 1
Day 2: 00:01

My suggestions and thoughts on causing the issue.

> Maths formula is in correct
> I belive the pad() function needs removed.
> Where the timer resets at 00:59 back to 0 i added code to increment day by 1 ++days but still no result was wondering if anyone could lend a hand or an more efficent code.

My game will be running like this
Day: 1 00:00 - counter counts 1 second every 15 seconds this allows me to have more days on my round and have more days in 1 actual real day givng the users better chances as its a round based game there will be prizes

Comment: @everyone sorry i said i removed the {Day: 1} out the label and changed it to <em>Day:</em><label='days'>1</label>

Comment: `pad(parseInt(totalSeconds / 60 == 24))` evaluates to `pad(parseInt(true))` or `pad(paseInt(false))`

Answer (score 0):

The code updating your text tries to calculate the day from the totalSeconds but you reset totalSeconds every time the clock ticks over a day. You do track this with your `dayUpdate` but you don't use it.

```js
let daysLabel = document.getElementById("days");
let minutesLabel = document.getElementById("minutes");
let hoursLabel = document.getElementById("hours");
let totalSeconds = 0;
let dayUpdate = 0;
setInterval(setTime, 10);

function setTime() {
  ++totalSeconds;
  if (totalSeconds / 60 == 24) {
    ++dayUpdate;
    totalSeconds = 0;
  }
  minutesLabel.innerHTML = pad(parseInt(totalSeconds % 60));
  hoursLabel.innerHTML = pad(parseInt(totalSeconds / 60));
  daysLabel.innerHTML = `Day: ${dayUpdate + 1}`; // +1 optional if you want day zero
}

function pad(val) {
  let valString = val + "";
  if (valString.length < 2) {
    return "0" + valString
  }
  return valString
}
```

```html
<label id="days">Day: 1</label> <label id="hours">00</label>:<label id="minutes">00</label><br />
```

Removing the math from your output, and only working with seconds (no separate days tracker) might be better? the following takes a time value and returns days, hours, minutes and seconds

```
function expandSeconds(time) {   
    let period = { DAY: 86400, HOUR: 3600, MINUTE: 60 } // number of seconds in period
    let days = parseInt(time / period.DAY,10)
    time -= days * period.DAY
    let hours = parseInt(time / period.HOUR, 10)
    time -= hours * period.HOUR
    let minutes = parseInt(time / period.MINUTE, 10)
    time -= minutes * period.MINUTE
    return { days: days, hours: hours, minutes: minutes, seconds: time }
}
```